# How to "append" a value with jQuery instead of replace it completely?

Tags: jquery

The way I understand val works is that when you do

```
$(".foo").val("x")
```

you literally replace the value for the input. Does anything in jQuery 2.x support a "append" like function instead? I found a unit/integration like scenario that would let me reproduce a real but ... except that val replaces the input's value completely instead of "just adding a single char" like my end user would.

Comment: no there isn't any "append" like feature in jquery:
at least you will have to do this.. 

`var v =  $(".foo").val(); $(".foo").val( v +"x")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access the callback function of `.val( cb )` and return the current value concatenated with a  string of your choice:

```js
$(".foo").val(function(i, currVal) {
   return currVal + "whatever";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="foo" tyle="text" value="A-">      <!-- A-whatever -->
<input class="foo" tyle="text" value="B-">      <!-- B-whatever -->
```

If you want a **jQuery method** like `.valAppend()` than you can create one:

```
$.fn.valAppend = function( str ) {
  return this.val( this[0].value + str );
};

// Use like:
$(".foo").valAppend( "whatever" );
```